# Highcharts - Final X-Axis label misaligned on point update

Tags: highcharts, alignment, label

My chart initially displays correctly. See attached image:

[site won't allow me to attach image, so here is link]

http://imgur.com/VDa2Xar

After updating the last point in the chart, the last label spontaneously misaligns itself. See attached image:

[site won't allow me to attach image, so here is link]

http://imgur.com/eZjAqOJ

The problem cropped up when upgrading from version 2 to 4.1.4. Is there an easy fix for this bug or must I revert back to version 2?

Comment: This will most likely require some code.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with [`xAxis.labels.overflow`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.overflow) but it suppose to be disabled. Indeed, live demo would be great.